# How to connect UIPickerView + Button + call dictionary to display in label

Tags: swift

I have a label, a picker (years), and a button.  I want to be able to select the year on the picker, hit the button, and then display data associated with the year (a dictionary).  Here's my code so far

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!


    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent      
    component: Int) -> Int {
        return years.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, 
    forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return years[row]
    }


    /*    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, 
    inComponent component: Int) {
        label.text = "\(years[row])"
    }

    */

   @IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
        label.text = 
    }
```

here is my Model:

```
 let years = ["2015", "2014", "2013", "2012"]

    let winners = [
        2015: "Patriots",
        2014: "Seahawks",
        2013: "Ravens",
        2012: "Giants"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a few things to make this work. First, make your viewController conform to the `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` and set your picker's data source and delegate in `viewDidLoad`. Then you'll want to use the delegate method `pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` to respond to changes to the pickerView. Store the selection in an instance variable and you should be good to go:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

    let years = [2015, 2014, 2013, 2012]

    let winners = [
        2015: "Patriots",
        2014: "Seahawks",
        2013: "Ravens",
        2012: "Giants"
    ]

    var selectedYear: Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return years.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectedYear = years[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return "\(years[row])"
    }


    @IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
        if let year = selectedYear {
            if let winner = winners[year] {
                label.text = winner
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  Now in label.text I don't want to return the year in my array, but the team that corresponds to the year in my dictionary.  How do I do that?  Switch statement maybe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454222/uipickerview-using-nsdictionary....Any Help?please