# UIPickerView Using NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary, uipickerview

I am new to Swift Programming Language.

I am trying to make a`UIPickerView` which work like select or listbox that contain key,value.If user select one from picker view,it gives me the key of that value.

I have been browsing for almost half of the day trying to figure this out.

All i got was`UIPickerView` using array results.All i want to know was how to store a Dictionary[key:value] in`UIPickerView` and if user select one of the value from picker,how to get the key.

Please Help.
With Regards

Comment: For you one simple solution. From  dictionary create two Array's one holding all key's and other one all values. Make sure index is same. Use one Array to populate the picker view, when user selects an item in picker view get the index for that item  in the array and use that index in other array to get value or key.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405965/uipickerview-with-nsdictionary

Comment: @Vizllx,I am just switch from Java Programmer.I dont know anything about Obj-C.Thank You.@Amit89,I will figure it out the solution that u gave me.Is there was anyway,all can help me.Thanks